# How can I set the scope to a http request in my app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ionic-framework, hapi.js

I would like to know how to set the scope to a http request in my Ionic App. We are using Hapi Framework for the Backend built with Node.JS. I'm working with a team so I don’t have enough knowledge on the server side since I'm working on the Ionic App.

Also, I'm setting a Bearer Token to the request header which is working fine. Below is my code.

Ionic App Http Request:

```
let params = { eventId: this.event_id, bearerToken: '' };  

let headers = new HttpHeaders();

headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${params.bearerToken}`);
headers.set('Scope', 'client');
console.log("Authorization bearer token: " + params.bearerToken);
//headers.append('scope', ['client']);
let options = { headers: headers, scope: 'client' };
return this.http
  .get(this.baseUrl + `getEventShops?eventId=${params.eventId}`, options)
  .pipe(map((response: any) => response)
    , catchError(this.handleError));
```

Node.JS Route Fragment:

```
exports.getEventShops = {
method: 'get',
path: '/event/getEventShops',
async handler(request) {
    const user = request.auth.credentials.userSession;
    let data = await shopController.getEventShops(request.query, user);
    return data;
},
config: {
    auth: {
        strategy: 'JwtAuth',
        scope: ['client']
    },
  ......
```

This is the error code I'm getting:

```
{
   "statusCode": 403,
   "error": "Forbidden",
   "message": "Insufficient scope"
}
```

I know the error is because I'm setting the scope the wrong way.

Comment: The 403 status indicates "forbidden" so either your authentication is not working as expected or your login credentials don't have enough permissions.

Comment: The problem is the scope (Hapi JS), I don’t know how to set the scope to the http request on the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that has to be set in the Bearer token, on the server side, not on the mobile one.

Answer (score 0):

In the add-on you registered to validate the scopes and the token, when everything goes well you must return the credentials and hapi validates that you are returning the reaches in the credentials, something like this:

```
return h.authenticated({ credentials: { scope: scopes } });
```

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is strictly an [English Q&A only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange). Posts containing anything else risk being [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). Please translate your answer to English only.